# How change this multiplication to solve: $(x,y) \cdot (x,y)=(2,0)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $\mathbb{Q}^{2}= \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}= \left\{(a,b): a,b
> \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$ be the set of rational numbers and we have two
>   operations $+$ and $\cdot$ for all $(a_{1},b_{1}),(a_{2},b_{2}) \in
> \mathbb{Q}^{2}$ by the following rule
>
> $$(a_{1},b_{1})+(a_{2},b_{2})=(a_{1}+a_{2},b_{1}+b_{2}),$$
>
> $$(a_{1},b_{1}) \cdot
> (a_{2},b_{2})=(a_{1}a_{2}-2b_{1}b_{2},a_{1}b_{2}+a_{2}b_{1}).$$
>   Is it necessary to change the multiplication in order to solve $(x,y) \cdot (x,y)=(2,0)$, so to find the square root of $(2,0)$?

$$(x,y) \cdot (x,y) = (2,0) \Leftrightarrow (x^{2}-2y^{2},xy+yx)=(2,0)$$

So we have $x^{2}-2y^{2}=2$ and $2xy=0$

but what's the question now? I don't get it..

Comment: Just solve it. We have $x=0$, so that $-2y^2=2$, or $y^2=-1$. This is impossible. Also $y=0$ is impossible. Ready!

Comment: Yeah, the question's phrasing is odd. I suspect the point is that there *isn't* such a pair of rational numbers $x,y$, but there would be if you changed the value to be $a_1a_2+2b_1b_2$. But the phrasing is far from clear.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Yes, what can $x$ be? Recall that $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solve for $x,y$. You have $2xy=0$ so $x=0$ or $y=0$. If $x=0$ then $-2y^2=2$, a contradiction so $y=0$. Then $x^2=2$. However $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational so there are no solutions.